# Unable to download apps requiring iOS 7+ on iOS 8

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

My iPhone 5 is updated to iOS 8.3 but when I'm trying to download any apps from the App Store, they keep telling me that I have to have an iOS 7.0 or higher.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that iOS8 is very buggy... As I read. If youre fine with it, you should downgrade for a while.

Comment: @TheBro21 Considering that is not an option for 99.9% of people (those who "didn't bother" to backup their SHSH blob while Apple was still signing updates for an earlier version...aka nearly everybody who owns an iPhone), and the majority of people are not finding iOS 8 "very buggy", your comment is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Michael, how long has this issue been occurring? Is it just for downloading "new" applications (ones that you have never downloaded before), or does it happen when trying to update apps that are already on your phone, too?